# A video file has different sizes when it streams with lighttpd

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, h.264, lighttpd

I was downloading video lectures on math using `wget`. Accidentally I had stopped by pressing Ctrl+C and continued with `wget --continue`. Here I noticed that the server responded with the file with different file size. The server uses `lighttpd`.

I am wondering why `lighttpd` responds with different file sizes for the same file?

The server responses are below.

First attempt:

```
$ wget -S http://www.server.com/lecture11940.mp4

--2015-07-23 20:04:28--  http://www.server.com/lecture/11940.mp4
Resolving www.server.com... 1.2.3.4
Connecting to www.server.com|1.2.3.4|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 18:03:33 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Location: http://www.server.com:8080/lecture11940.mp4
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Length: 239
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://www.server.com:8080/lecture11940.mp4 [following]
```

Redirect:

```
--2015-07-23 20:04:35--  http://www.server.com:8080/lecture11940.mp4

Connecting to www.server.com|1.2.3.4|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  X-Mod-H264-Streaming: version=2.2.9
  Content-Type: video/mp4
  ETag: "745841726"
  Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 12:24:08 GMT
  Content-Length: 533771778
  Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 18:03:36 GMT
  Server: lighttpd/1.4.19
Length: 533771778 (509M) [video/mp4]
Saving to: '11940.mp4'
```

The second attempt:

```
$ wget -S --continue http://www.server.com/lecture11940.mp4

--2015-07-23 20:04:51--  http://www.server.com/lecture11940.mp4
Resolving www.server.com... 1.2.3.4
Connecting to www.server.com|1.2.3.4|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 302 Found
  Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 18:03:49 GMT
  Server: Apache
  Location: http://www.server.com:8080/lecture11940.mp4
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Content-Length: 239
  Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Location: http://www.server.com:8080/lecture11940.mp4 [following]
```

Redirect:

```
--2015-07-23 20:04:51--  http://www.server.com:8080/lecture11940.mp4

Connecting to www.server.com|1.2.3.4|:8080... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
  Expires: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 22:03:49 GMT
  Cache-Control: max-age=14400
  Content-Type: video/mp4
  Accept-Ranges: bytes
  ETag: "1834748875"
  Last-Modified: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 12:24:08 GMT
  Content-Range: bytes 122057-533786493/533786494
  Content-Length: 533664437
  Date: Thu, 23 Jul 2015 18:03:49 GMT
  Server: lighttpd/1.4.19
Length: 533786494 (509M), 533664437 (509M) remaining [video/mp4]
Saving to: '11940.mp4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response to the initial wget request is H264 Streaming, indicated by

```
X-Mod-H264-Streaming: version=2.2.9
```

whereas the response to the second wget request (wget --continue, a Range request) is a byte-range response for part of a file (*not* H264 Streaming), indicated by

```
Content-Range: bytes 122057-533786493/533786494
```

Answer (score -1):

This was lighttpd's video streaming mechanism.
[Here have some discuss](http://h264.code-shop.com/trac/discussion/topic/142)

> When a Range Request header is present, the request is forwarded to the >mod_staticfile module and the H264 module is skipped.
>
> When there is no range request header, the file is processed by the H264 >module and may differ in size from the original as it rewrites the headers (and/or moves the moov atom to the front of the file, etc...).